# How can I add labels on a barplot with geom_line in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a barplot with a geom_line over it. I want to add labels that appear on top of the geom_line and not on top of the bars.

I'm using this code:

```
    ggplot(media_movel, aes(x=SE_PRI_SIN, y=n, fill= " ", group = 1)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge', color = "black", fill = "skyblue4") +
  geom_line(data = media_movel, aes(y = media, color = "MÉDIA MÓVEL"), size = 0.75) +
  geom_text(aes(label= media), hjust= 0.5, vjust = -1, size=3, color= "black")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(media_movel$n)+250), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1)))+
  labs(fill = " ", x = "Semana Epidemiológica", y = "Número de Casos") +
  scale_colour_manual(" ", values=c("CASOS" = "skyblue4", "MÉDIA MÓVEL" = "red"))+
  theme_minimal(base_size = 10)+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, colour="black"), 
        axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black"))
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I want the labels on top of the red line. How can I do that?

Here's some reproductible data:

```
data <- data.frame(SE_PRI_SIN= c("SE 29", "SE 30", "SE 31", "SE 32", "SE 33","SE 34", "SE 35", "SE 36",
                                 "SE 37", "SE 38"),
                   n = c(5, 10, 28, 33, 78, 19, 50, 88, 97, 7824),
                   media_movel = c(494.5, 525.5, 568, 645, 700, 618, 476.5, 370.5, 299.5, 4994))
```

Comment: I don't think that this will work in this form. The line has no points to put the label. What you could do is create geom_point smaller then the size of the line with them same color and paste the labels to geom_point. If you want to get help in this way, we would need your data.

Comment: @TarJae edited the post with part of my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the provided data, we get this:

I have changed the code a little: By the way it works also without `geom_point` :-)

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=SE_PRI_SIN, y=media_movel, group=1))+
  geom_col(aes(y= n), position = position_dodge(), color = "black", fill = "skyblue4")+
  geom_point(color = "red", size = 0.75)+
  geom_text(
    label=media_movel$media_movel, 
    nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 300, 
    check_overlap = T
  )+
  geom_line(aes(color = "MÉDIA MÓVEL"), size = 0.75) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(media_movel$n)+250), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1)))+
  labs(fill = " ", x = "Semana Epidemiológica", y = "Número de Casos") +
  scale_colour_manual(" ", values=c("CASOS" = "skyblue4", "MÉDIA MÓVEL" = "red"))+
  theme_minimal(base_size = 10)+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, colour="black"), 
        axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black"))
```

[image]